# ERROR: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types'

Tags: mysql, database, configuration, sequelize.js, database-migration

1. C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yoobou\Yoobou>sequelize db:migrate

   Sequelize CLI [Node: 14.15.1, CLI: 6.2.0, ORM: 6.3.5]

   Loaded configuration file "config\config.json". Using environment
   "development".
   == 20201207141344-create-producteurs: migrating =======

   ERROR: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types' Require stack:

   - C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Yoobou\Yoobou\migrations\20201207141344-create-producteurs.js
   - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\umzug\lib\migration.js
   - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sequelize-cli\node_modules\umzug\lib\index.js
   - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\core\migrator.js
   - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\commands\migrate.js
   - C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sequelize-cli\lib\sequelize

   //MIGRATION 20201207141344-create-producteurs.js

   'use strict'; const { UniqueConstraintError } =
   require('sequelize/types');

   module.exports = {   up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.createTable('PRODUCTEURS', {
   id: {
   allowNull: false,
   autoIncrement: true,
   primaryKey: true,
   type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
   },

   ```
     first_name: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       unique: true,
     },
     last_name: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
     },
     email: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
       Unique: true,
     },
     password: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
     },
     avatar: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.STRING,
     },
     createdAt: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.DATE,
     },
     updatedAt: {
       allowNull: false,
       type: Sequelize.DATE,
     },
   });   },   down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
   await queryInterface.dropTable('PRODUCTEURS');   }, };
   // ASSOCIATION MODELS  'use strict'; const { Model } = require('sequelize'); module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
   ```

   class ADMINISTRATEUR extends Model {
   /**
   * Helper method for defining associations.
   * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
   * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
   */
   associate(models) {
   // define association here
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.CLIENTS);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.PRODUITS);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.ADRESSE_CLIENTS);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.CATEGORY_PRODUITS);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.COMMANDES);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.PRODUCTEURS);
   models.ADMINISTRATEUR.hasMany(models.AVIS);
   }   }   ADMINISTRATEUR.init(
   {
   first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   email: DataTypes.STRING,
   password: DataTypes.STRING,
   avatar: DataTypes.STRING,
   },
   {
   sequelize,
   modelName: 'ADMINISTRATEUR',
   }   );   return ADMINISTRATEUR; }; 'use strict'; const {   Model } = require('sequelize'); module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) =>
   {   class PRODUCTEURS extends Model {
   /**
   * Helper method for defining associations.
   * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
   * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
   */
   static associate(models) {
   // define association here
   models.PRODUCTEURS.belongsTo(models.ADMINISTRATEUR , {
   foreignKey: {
   allowNull: false
   }
   });
   models.PRODUCTEURS.hasMany(models.CLIENTS);
   models.PRODUCTEURS.hasMany(models.PRODUITS);
   models.PRODUCTEURS.hasMany(models.ADRESSE_CLIENTS);
   models.PRODUCTEURS.hasMany(models.CATEGORY_PRODUITS);
   models.PRODUCTEURS.hasMany(models.COMMANDES);
   }   };   PRODUCTEURS.init({
   first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
   email: DataTypes.STRING,
   password: DataTypes.STRING,
   avatar: DataTypes.STRING   }, {
   sequelize,
   modelName: 'PRODUCTEURS',   });   return PRODUCTEURS; };

Comment: can you show `20201207141344-create-producteurs.js`?

Comment: @Anatoly 
I put it back in the question

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer I had to put the variable "const {UniqueConstraintError} = require ('sequelize / types')" in comment and retype sequelize db: migrate

Comment: what? can you explain that a little bit more