# Cannot find module 'sequelize/types'

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

anyone knows why i am getting this error
this is my code

```
"use strict";
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize/types");

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("dummytables", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      },
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("dummytables");
  },
};
```

when am trying to run this command `sequelize db:migrate`
and its showing me `ERROR: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types'`

my dependencies file

```
  "dependencies": {
"@types/sequelize": "^4.28.9",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "sequelize": "^6.5.0",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.2.0"  }
```

any solution need help

Comment: Are you sure you have that module installed? Show me the dependencies part in the package.json file.

Comment: `{
  "name": "sqlSequelize",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mysql2": "^2.2.5",
    "sequelize": "^6.5.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"

}
` @m_hm0ud see

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: not using typescript @m_hm0ud

Comment: Well I searched on npm website and there's no such package called sequelize/types. There's @types/sequelize which is for making sequelize compatible with typescript.

Comment: i tried that too but no help @m_hm0ud but thank you

Comment: This question could have an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65204670/error-cannot-find-module-sequelize-types?rq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
"use strict";
//const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize/types"); // Remove this line

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable("dummytables", {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      },
      id: {
        type: DataTypes.NUMBER,
      },
      first_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      last_name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, DataTypes) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable("dummytables");
  },
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/nkhs/node-sequelize : there is migration sample files

Answer (score 4):

If you change the second line to;

```
const { DataTypes } = require("sequelize");
```

It should work fine.

Comment: The better way is to replace the `Sequelize` parameter in the async callback to `DataTypes`, Importing `DataTypes` and presence of `Sequelize` can lead to certain conflicts, atleast that's what I think

Answer (score 0):

A better fix would be to just install Sequelize like;

`const Sequelize = require("sequelize");`

then use it like;

```
first_name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull: false,
},
```

You might not even need to do the importation because up() would give it to you for free, You just need to replace `DataTypes` with `Sequelize`.

```
async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error, may be can happen when you use **auto import** and it import **sequelize/types**, you can find in code has 'sequelize/types' and **delete** it in code of you should change

```
const {DataTypes} = require('sequelize');
```